# In Java serialisation why does J signify a long and L signify an Object?

Tags: java, oop, serialization

When you serialise an object in Java, the letter J is used to signify the next bytes represent a `long` and the letter L is used to signify that an `Object` is next, but why? Why not use O for `Object` and L for `long`?

Comment: Maybe because O is confused with 0?

Comment: Apart from "That's how the specification was written", I'd be surprised to see an actual reason

Comment: J came after I and I is int, so J would be long.  Not quite sure where they got L, but it all goes back into the mists of history, when computers were steam-powered.  (BTW, technically this thread probably runs afoul of the "not a real question" criteria, but it is mildly interesting nonetheless.)

Comment: Also, why must every valid `.class` file contain the magic number `0xCAFEBABE`? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These letters certainly were choosen because of conflicts. A guesswork of that conflicts:

- **C** was taken for **char**. So, they used **L** for **class**.
- **L** was taken for **class**. So, they used **J** for **long**.
- **B** was taken for **byte**. So, they used **Z** for **boolean**.

By the way, '**L**' doesn't mean '**Object**', but '**fully-qualified-class**'.

Comment: I'm not sure that's exactly the rationale, but it's plausible (as is the idea that they picked letters out of a Scrabble bag).

Comment: Do you have a source for this statement, or is it just guesswork?

Comment: Yes. It's just a guesswork! If I'd found a source, I'd put it here.